# Truffle testing proxy contracts and delegation

Tags: truffle, proxy-contracts

I have a proxy contract ( [Openzeppelin proxy](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/Proxy.sol) ) and a custom Logic contract.

the logic contract has a method

```
function asd() public pure returns(uint256){
    return 5;
  }
```

since the proxy has a fallback that delegates the calls to the logic contract, I was expecting to be able to call something like

```
proxy.asd()
```

from truffle console, but that's not the case since I get an error `proxy.asd is not a function`

I think I am missing some beginner information here, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should someone have this problem, this was the solution.

Better understanding truffle contract abstraction is the key.

If you have something like this migration:

```
const Box = artifacts.require("Box");
const ERC1967Proxy = artifacts.require("ERC1967Proxy")


module.exports = async function(deployer) {
    await deployer.deploy(Box)
    const boxInstance = await Box.deployed()

    await deployer.deploy(ERC1967Proxy, boxInstance.address, "0x")
    proxyInstance = await ERC1967Proxy.deployed()

    console.log('BOX: ', boxInstance.address);
    console.log('Proxy: ', proxyInstance.address);
}
```

then from the console you'll have available **Box** and **ERC1967Proxy**

In order to properly access the Box methods via the proxy you need to use BOX abi, called on the proxy address, so:

```
let box_via_proxy = await Box.at("0xPROXY_ADDRESS")
```

this allows you to use Box method called on the proxy contract, which will use the original box code via the fallback function of ERC19267

Comment: Got an error saying Box.at is not a function.

Comment: it's difficult to identify the issue without the code, try opening a new question , there is probably some small mistake somewhere